# Perl 5.18 | Archive::ZIP 1.68 | Recursive files not included in ZIP

Tags: perl

I have to fix a Perl script which is having issues adding files recursively. As I am not a Perl programmer this is kinda hard for me, hope that somebody will have a clue for me.

What the script has to do is ZIP a directory from a mounted (NAS) share. I am running into the issue that the ZIP is created as expected, is a valid ZIP and does contain the directory structure of the original directory. By example, when I try to ZIP a directory like "/mounted_dir/to_zip/" which contains a sub-directory called "sub_dir" which contains a file like "filetozip.txt" I will only find the directory structure in the ZIP file. No errors are shown.

I tested it by creating a 2 pertty simple scripts to test:

```
use Archive::Zip qw( :ERROR_CODES :CONSTANTS );
my $zip = Archive::Zip->new();
my $dir_member = $zip->addDirectory( '/mounted_dir/to_zip/' );
unless ( $zip->writeToFileNamed('/tmp/someZip.zip') == AZ_OK ) {
    die 'write error';
}
```

and with AddTree function:

```
use Archive::Zip qw( :ERROR_CODES :CONSTANTS );
my $zip = Archive::Zip->new();
$zip->addTree( '/mounted_dir/to_zip/' );
unless ( $zip->writeToFileNamed('/tmp/someZip.zip') == AZ_OK ) {
    die 'write error';
}
```

Both with same results.

If I move the "to_zip" directory to the local filesystem, everything is working as expected. ZIP file is created with directories and files.

This has been working in the past on an older Fedora/Perl version. I had to update Fedora to a newer version because of the lack of SMB3 support in my version. With that upgrade my Perl moved to version 5.18. Archive::ZIP is at the latest 1.68 version.

When I access the directories and files on the command line I can do whatever I want with them. Create, rename, edit, remove, etc. etc. Also used the default Fedora ZIP and TAR tools, all working. So I think this is not a directory or file permission. Feels like I am missing some option in Perl / Archive::ZIP, but as said I am not a Perl progammer and do miss essential basic knowledge.

Comment: I wonder if the mounted directory is getting disconnected by some network issue and then reconnects *after* getting the file list. Try adding something like `system("find /mounted_dir/to_zip/")` at the top of the script to make sure all the files are showing up okay.

Comment: I have tested your suggestion, it will output all files in the directory.

For your information, I have 2 mounts to 2 different servers and it will not work on both mounts.

Comment: Any chance to_zip is a symlink?

Comment: `addDirectory` is supposed to only add the directory entry, not the files inside the directory. Only `addTree` is supposed to add all the files inside the directory too.

Comment: Since `addTree` is using File::Find internally - could you check if all the files are returned by `perl -MFile::Find=find -e 'find(sub { print $File::Find::name,"\n" }, q[/mounted_dir/to_zip/])'`